# Help configuring amdgpu config file for three monitors?

Tags: drivers, xorg, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I upgraded from 14.04.3 to 16.04 and got no error messages I'm aware of. It boots and I usually use Gnome fallback, but have tried other environments. I have a three monitor system powered by a fairly recent and powerful AMD Radeon card. I know all about 16.04 not fully supporting AMD until Early Fall [If I'm lucky], but the amdgpu driver has been working for others. I think I finally found the 16.04 monitor config files [not where it was in 14.04], but do not know if it is the correct file, and more importantly how to tell it to see and configure my three monitors for a large desktop. It only sees one monitor, it displays on two [they are each a copy of the other] and my background image is not there [black desktop], nor are the folders and other items on my desktop in fallback - yet they are all listed and are there. I'd really appreciate the help now, and hope by late August or Sept./Oct. there is real support for AMD again. Thanks in advance.

[xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf file in 16.04 and old xorg.conf files](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=268987&d=1462950012)

Update: All but one possibly unrelated matter solved! I had (wrongly) assumed that during the upgrade 16.04 would have removed all the old video drivers [flgrx*]....and a look in Synaptic seemed to indicate that it had. Wrong. They were still there! When I purged them all and rebooted, the computer recognized the three monitors correctly and there was no need to edit any config file for it. The only issue still remaining is that while it shows that my background image is 'there'...it is not seen; and all I see is a black desktop - although programs open fine so far and I can access those things on my desktop by going to Places and then Desktop.

I spoke [wrote] too early that all was fixed. Thought it was, but now the monitors are not in the correct order and I see no way to order them other than to know where the config file is and how to change it...though I think I can figure that out if someone would tell me where it is and what it is called. The is a program to handle the monitors, but I tried all variants and things only got worse. It doesn't allow one to move the monitor it considers 'primary'...and that is likely in the wrong location.
Moving the mouse or panel only to have it jump into a non-contiguous area is very upsetting. Thanks.